# Sending the value of a state in a input field onSubmit with react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I have `price` , which is a state, if I write on the form it does not detect the input when I click the submit button and I get as an error:

`voucherPrice is a required field`

and in the dev tools console:

`Warning: Received NaN for the` value `attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string.`

```
import React from "react";
import { useStylesPriceSelection } from "../../styles/stepStyles";
import clsx from "clsx";
import { Input } from "reactstrap";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import * as yup from "yup";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";

const schema = yup
  .object({
    voucherPrice: yup.number().positive().required(),
  })
  .required();

function PriceSelection(props) {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });
  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);

  const classes = useStylesPriceSelection();
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);
  const [price, setPrice] = useState("");

  const handleSelectedBox = (ev) => {
    console.log("", price);
    setSelected(ev.target.getAttribute("data-boxprice"));
    setPrice(parseInt(ev.target.getAttribute("data-price")));
  };

  const handlePriceInputChange = (ev) => {
    console.log("change", price);
    setPrice(parseInt(ev.target.value));
  };

  const priceBox1 = 25;
  const priceBox2 = 50;
  const priceBox3 = 75;
  const priceBox4 = 100;

  return (
    <div>
      <section className={classes.priceBoxWrap}>
        <div
          data-boxprice="1"
          data-price={`${priceBox1}`}
          onClick={(ev) => handleSelectedBox(ev)}
          className={clsx(
            classes.priceBox,
            ((selected === "1" && price === priceBox1) ||
              price === priceBox1) &&
              classes.priceBoxSelected
          )}
        >
          {`${priceBox1}€`}
        </div>

        <div
          data-boxprice="2"
          data-price={`${priceBox2}`}
          onClick={(ev) => handleSelectedBox(ev)}
          className={clsx(
            classes.priceBox,
            ((selected === "2" && price === priceBox2) ||
              price === priceBox2) &&
              classes.priceBoxSelected
          )}
        >
          {`${priceBox2}€`}
        </div>
      </section>

      <section className={classes.priceBoxWrap}>
        <div
          data-boxprice="3"
          data-price={`${priceBox3}`}
          onClick={(ev) => handleSelectedBox(ev)}
          className={clsx(
            classes.priceBox,
            ((selected === "3" && price === priceBox3) ||
              price === priceBox3) &&
              classes.priceBoxSelected
          )}
        >
          {`${priceBox3}€`}
        </div>

        <div
          data-boxprice="4"
          data-price={`${priceBox4}`}
          onClick={(ev) => handleSelectedBox(ev)}
          className={clsx(
            classes.priceBox,
            ((selected === "4" && price === priceBox4) ||
              price === priceBox4) &&
              classes.priceBoxSelected
          )}
        >
          {`${priceBox4}€`}
        </div>
      </section>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Input
          onChange={(ev) => handlePriceInputChange(ev)}
          type="number"
          value={price}
          innerRef={register("voucherPrice", { required: true })}
        ></Input>
        <p>{errors.voucherPrice?.message}</p>

        <Button
          variant="contained"
          // onClick={props.handleNext}
          sx={{ mt: 1, mr: 1 }}
          type="submit"
        >
          {"Continue"}
        </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default PriceSelection;
```

Comment: what is the value of price ? can you console.log its value ?

Comment: so I put a console log within `handlePriceInputChange` to check it out, and nothing comes out

Comment: I have updated with the whole script

Comment: price contains an integer, but when I click submit, it says its NaN